# Kingston SSD UV300 how to set password

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I always used TrueCrypt on my Windows 8 and in Windows 10. I login to my Windows, normally and mount a partition using TrueCrypt.

I know that using SSD it already encrypts all data on disk so I should not use Truecrypt cause hardware encryption is way betttr than software encryption.

My question is: I cant find anyway to set a password to my Kinghost UV300 SSD. My BIOS does not support HD password so I cant use BIOS to set the password to my SSD.

Even if I used BIOS to set a password I see no point into this: if my password is gonna be saved on BIOS any person could access it and retrieve it, cause if anyone turn on my computer it will not ask for a password, BIOS will automatically provide the password. So I see no point using BIOS password if the hacker can have access to my computer (phisically). He just needs to turn on my computer and it will not ask a single password cause BIOS will already provide the password to SSD.

I know I am doing something wrong and I may be saying stupid things, but please point me to the right direction, I already read lots of inofmration at SO and none helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all not all SSDs are equipped with hardware encryption. So you need to check its specification. (Whether ATA Enhanced Security Erase takes less time than ATA Security Erase can give you a hint as well.)

Personally I found the hardware encryption available on internal drives not really for security purpose, at least not the kind of security most people expect. (I am not talking about those with "Opal" encryption though.)

The main purpose of the hardware encryption is to allow one to quickly and securely erase the whole drive, since it's basically regeneration of the encryption key.

Surely you can set ATA password on the drive, but the encryption may not add an extra layer of security *in addition to* that since they are not designed to work with each other. If someone is able to circumvent the ATA password, chances are he won't need to further deal with the "encryption", just like you don't need to deal with it when you access the data.

Also as you have already noticed, not all BIOS/UEFI supports unlocking ATA password (even if it does it may not work *well*), so it's not really feasible to "implement" ATA password locking on *system drive(s)*.

Anyway, on Linux the most common way to set and unlock ATA password is through the utility `hdparm`. I am not aware of a decent one in Windows (you can probably find some Windows ports of hdparm though). Would be glad to see a recommendation from someone too.

Comment: thanks man! So what do you recommend? I know my computer does not support BIOS password to SSD. I also know Kingston UV300 has hardware encryption builted in and the default password is blank. So how do I set this password to something different than blank?

Comment: As my answer implied, I do NOT recommend you to take the ATA password approach. Instead, just "further" encrypt it with BitLocker or so (not sure about TrueCrypt since it's unmaintained). If you insists on setting the ATA password then you will need to look for an hdparm alternative in Windows, but as I said, it can't be done on a system drive, since your BIOS cannot unlock it for booting.

Comment: Yes, I thought about bitlocker but I hear many people complaining about shear on SSD and significantly decrease in span life. Related to bitlocker I really really dont recommend it, using Truecrypt is MUCH safer. In the recent Apple case, Bill gates offended Apple cause it didnt comply with FBI. That was really clear to me that if Microsoft is compelled to break Bitlocker encryption it will be more than glad to help any goverment or organization. After that bitlocker became crap to me, complete crap.

Comment: I don't know. It doesn't sound making sense that any software encryption can harm your SSD. Anyway I do not really know much about which software encryption is good or so. I guess my only advice is try to look for some maintained fork or so (if any) of TrueCrypt. Even the homepage of TrueCrypt is a tutorial of migrating to BitLocker now: http://truecrypt.sourceforge.net/